java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.BufferRecycler.releaseToPool()'
I've upgraded Jackson from 2.16.1 to 2.18.2 in my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '8.1.1'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "${sonarqubeVersion}"
}

ext {
    awsLambdaJavaCoreVersion = '1.2.3'
    awsLambdaEventsVersion = '3.12.0'
    jacksonDatabindVersion = '2.18.2'
    awsLambdaTransformerVersion = '3.1.0'
    guavaVersion = '33.2.1-jre'
    javaJwtVersion = '4.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":fdx-6")
    implementation (project(":common")) {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot'
        exclude group: 'software.amazon.awssdk', module: 'url-connection-client'
    }
    implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:sqs"
    implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:lambda"
    implementation "org.springframework:spring-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:6.2.5"
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:$awsLambdaJavaCoreVersion"
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:$awsLambdaEventsVersion"
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events-sdk-transformer:$awsLambdaTransformerVersion"
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.6.0"
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:dynamodb-lock-client:1.2.0'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb-enhanced'
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonDatabindVersion"
        implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonDatabindVersion"
        implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:$jacksonDatabindVersion"
    implementation "com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:${nimbusJoseVersion}"
    implementation "io.netty:netty-codec-http:${nettyHttpVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"
    implementation "com.auth0:java-jwt:$javaJwtVersion"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:$jacksonDatabindVersion"
    implementation "com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:${nimbusJoseVersion}"
    //opentelemetry
    compileOnly "io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-api"
    compileOnly "io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-aws-lambda-events-2.2:${opentelemetryInstrumentationVersionAlpha}"
    compileOnly "io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-aws-sdk-2.2:${opentelemetryInstrumentationVersionAlpha}"
    implementation "io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-java-http-client:${opentelemetryInstrumentationVersionAlpha}"
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.6.0"
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-layout-template-json:2.17.1'

    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapStructVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapStructVersion}"

    testImplementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-tests:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:${mapStructVersion}"
    testImplementation 'uk.org.webcompere:system-stubs-jupiter:2.1.6'
    testImplementation "io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-aws-sdk-2.2:${opentelemetryInstrumentationVersionAlpha}"
}

Now this Java code
@UtilityClass
public class ObjectMapperUtil {

    public static final TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> STRING_OBJ_TYPE_REF = new TypeReference<>() {
    };
    public static final TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> STRING_STRING_TYPE_REF = new TypeReference<>() {
    };

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
            .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .addModule(new AfterburnerModule())
            .build();

    public static String toJsonString(Object obj) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error converting object to JSON", e);
        }
    }
}

throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.BufferRecycler.releaseToPool()':
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.BufferRecycler.releaseToPool()'

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:4059)
    at com.c.o.common.utils.ObjectMapperUtil.toJsonString(ObjectMapperUtil.java:29)

Any ideas how could I fix this without dependency downgrade?

I couldn't reproduce your error. And according to Jackson core's repository releaseToPool() seems to be still in BufferRecycler and unchanged since version 2.16. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/jackson-core-2.18.2/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/BufferRecycler.java#L264 This might be a useless attempt, but have you tried clearing your dependencies and downloading them again?

See my answer below, there were transitive dependencies with versions 2.14.2 and 2.15.4 without that method

Took me a while to write my comment while I was looking for the repo, and in the meantime your answer appeared without being loaded. Well done!

The culprit appeared to be com.auth0:java-jwt:4.4.0 for it is transitively dependent on com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2 and com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.4. Here's the output of gradle dependencies:
+--- com.auth0:java-jwt:4.4.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2 -> 2.18.2
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.18.2 -> 2.15.4
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.4 -> 2.18.2
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.18.2 -> 2.15.4 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.18.2 -> 2.15.4 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.18.2 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.18.2 (c)
|         |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:2.18.2 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.18.2 -> 2.15.4
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.4 -> 2.18.2 (*)
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.18.2 (*)

There void com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.BufferRecycler indeed does not declare releaseToPool() method.
To fix this I've enforced use of 2.18.2 for all Jackson-related dependencies by adding the following config into build.gradle:
configurations {
    all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group.startsWith("com.fasterxml.jackson")) {
                details.useVersion("$jacksonDatabindVersion")
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is the dependency tree after:
+--- com.auth0:java-jwt:4.4.0
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2 -> 2.18.2
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.18.2
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.18.2
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.18.2 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.18.2 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.18.2 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.18.2 (c)
|         |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:2.18.2 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.18.2
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.18.2 (*)
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.18.2 (*)

With the newer version method void com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.BufferRecycler.releaseToPool() is resolved.
